# batch file to check cpu and output to txt

Tags: batch, windows-command-prompt

I'm trying to write a simple batch file to check the cpu of the computer every 30 seconds and output to txt file with the current time.
I want each line to be like:

```
Line1: %time% %cpu%
Line2: %time% %cpu%
```

This is what I came up with so far, didn't work:

```
:loop

echo %TIME% > C:\test.txt

wmic cpu get loadpercentage > C:\test.txt

timeout 30

goto loop
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the native Windows performance monitoring tools for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big issue with your sample is the redirection operator '>' - This will always overwrite the data in test.txt with the new data being entered. Use '>>' to append the output to the end of the file without deleting the information that is already in the file.

Instead of fixing your batch script, this PowerShell one-liner will give you the same result with much less effort.

```
While($true){Get-WmiObject win32_processor | Select-Object @{L="Date";E={Get-Date}},LoadPercentage,SystemName | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Append CPU.csv; Start-Sleep -Seconds 5}
```

You can even target a remote computer with:

> Get-WmiObject -ComputerName `<`computer`>`

Sorry for not answering your specific question. I hope you will find what I have provided to be useful.